# Login using MSSQL Local server on SmarterASP.NET online Website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, aspx-user-control

This is the error when I login my account in my live website using smarterASP.net. Is it possible to get data source from a local server to a live website? is there anyone encounter with this problem?

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
    The user name or password is incorrect
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
    
    Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The user name or password is incorrect
    
    Source Error:
    
    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
    
    Stack Trace:
    
    
    [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect]
    
    [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +947
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +342
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +726
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +91
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +438
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +79
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +201
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +156
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +92
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +219
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +101
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +121
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +162
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +111
       JIIs.login.btn_login_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\JIIs\JIIs\login.aspx.vb:15
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9795798
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +211
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1696
```

Comment: Have you created your database on their control panel? From above error message, your connection string is incorrect.

Comment: No I did not but I am trying to connect the online website in my MSSQL local dbase and I just want to know if this is possible or not